# How to make sure API calls completes before another page loads in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making an api call in my react project in app.js.What is happening is that I am getting response from this API after some time, till then my other component which is using this repsonse breaks, so i have to make sure that unless getSubscriptionStatusCallback is not called don't proceed ahead.

```
getSubscriptionStatus(context) {
    console.log('inside api');
    if (!context.userInfo || context.userInfo.UserIdentified === '0')
      return

    let cacheManager = new CacheManager({
      apiName: 'getSubscriptionStatus',
      cacheKey: CacheKeys.SubscriptionStatus(context, ''),
      loader: GetSubscriptionStatusApi.get,
      callback: this.getSubscriptionStatusCallback,
      ttlInSecs: 10
    })
    let params = {
      'OPXUserID': context.userInfo.OPXUserID,
      'ProductType': 'APPSTORE',
      'SiteID': context.siteProperties.SiteID,
    }
    cacheManager.getObject(context, '', params)
  }

  getSubscriptionStatusCallback =(json) => {
    let context = this.state.context
    context.subscriptionStatus = json
    this.setState({context: context})
    console.log("testing"+context.subscriptionStatus.StatusCode);
    console.log(this.className, 'getSubscriptionStatusCallback', context)
  }
```

Comment: You should just be able to check a prop to decide if a component should mount.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should conditionally render the component which requires the data from your api as props.

```
hasReceivedData ? <Component> : ''
```

Make 'hasReceivedData' a state and trigger the api call in the lifecycle method 'componentDidMount()', update the state in the callback.

To improve the user experience you could show a spinner till the data is loaded

```
hasReceivedData ? <Component> : '<Spinner>'
```